# Inconsistent length for NodeList

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

So, I'm experimenting with `html/css/js` for the first time and I've encountered and issue that doesn't make much sense (at least to me).

So, when the page is loaded I insert some options in a `<ul>` (The options are NOT there since the begginning). After all of the options have been inserted I try to get all of them using something along:

```js
const dropdown = document.getElementById("selector");
const children = dropdown.childNodes;
```

However when I use `console.log(children)` I'm getting something like this:[image]

But when I use `children.length` I'm getting the value of 0. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I tried running your code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4gpdm5c/5/) and it works fine. Can you provide more code?

Comment: @MarkoBorković I've written in the post but possibly its not clear enough, but the elements are not in the html since the beginning. I add them with js and after I've added them, I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, sry for the trouble but apparently I need to wait a bit before trying to fetch it all. I added a setTimeout to the function that retrieves it and now it works. Thanks all!

Comment: Have a look at my answer. setTimeout is not a good way to wait for elements to load into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You can use childElementCount to get the count of children.

```
dropdown.childElementCount
```

Comment: Yeah, I've thougth of using that, but when I use `children[0]` (per example) I get `undefined`. (Forgot to add this to the post)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Perhaps I am missing something, but in the example below everything works as expected. the result of `children.length` is 11 (only 5 nodes are `li`). One possible problem is related to the way `console.log` works. Logging objects directly [is not advisable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects). If you have problems, you can check with `debugger`.

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector("ul");
const children = dropdown.childNodes;

console.log(children.length);
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've written in the post but possibly its not clear enough, but the elements are not in the html since the beginning. I add them with js and after I've added them, I do this. Possibly is related to that?

Comment: I had taken it for granted that you called `children.length` after the (synchronous) insertion. In that case, it does not matter. If so, in my opinion the most likely source of the problem is `console.log`, as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping your JS in a setTimeout() function, wrap it inside an eventHandler.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Your JS code here
}
```

This will make sure to fire your code only after all elements have been loaded into the DOM

Also, don't use `dropdown.childNodes` if you only want to calculate the number of `li` tags inside the list. `childNodes` will return both HTMLElements and TextNodes. So if you have something written between the `li` tags, that text will also show up as a Node.

Instead, use `dropdown.children`, which will only return a list of elements.

Comment: Using this method, it seems like it never "loads" I just keep waiting forever and nothing happens. I've tried adding a `console.log("loaded")` inside that Listener but its never triggered